# In Joomla, how do you create a 3x3 (9-grid) code for index.php?

Tags: php, html, css, joomla

I need to display this in the index.php file and nothing is working. All my articles are not positioning correctly. I'm using this as the code:

```
<div class="span3">
 <jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-0" />
 <jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-1" />
 <jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-2" />
 <jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-3" />
 <jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-4" />
 <jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-5" />
</div>
<div class="span3">
 <jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-6" />
 <jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-7" />
 <jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-8" />
 <jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-9" />
 <jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-10" />
 <jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-11" />
 <jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-12" />
 <jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-13" />
 <jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-14" />
</div>
```

Comment: I've read some joomla documentation but first off you need three columns first to have a three column layout. Can you also supply the css you are using? This will make the question easier to answer.

Comment: The CSS is over 1000 lines long... is there a specific section you'd like me to post? I thought there might be a standard way to do this.

Comment: There are many ways to do this, and many different frameworks. I'm checking documentation now for joomla for an explanation.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: I was too slow, the answer below is best. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start by checking that your index.php file is loading Bootstrap 2.3 and not Bootstrap 3.3, because if it's loading v3.3 you would need to change your classes to `<div class="col-md-3"></div>`

If you aren't sure which version of Bootstrap your template is loading, you could use web inspector and look at the CSS files, or share a link to your page here.

Good luck!

Comment: You need a "row" or "row-flud" div around those other divs, and use "span4" in three columns for a three column grid if your bootstrap hasn't been updated to v3.

Comment: You're correct @NathanielFlick, my oversight with the span, should be span4 for a 3x3 grid.